# How does Android Autobahn Websocket client detect connection loss?

Tags: android, websocket, autobahn

I am using Android Autobahn client for communication with a web socket server. I need to know how the client detects tcp connection loss. Does it send TCP heart probes to detect this?

PS: error code : de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocket.ConnectionHandler.CLOSE_CONNECTION_LOST

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code, the `CLOSE_CONNECTION_LOST` error code is emitted when the endpoint calls close with an abnormal close code:

```
final int tavendoCloseCode = (close.mCode == 1000) ? ConnectionHandler.CLOSE_NORMAL : ConnectionHandler.CLOSE_CONNECTION_LOST;
```

I don't know exactly how your router is implemented, but in the source code, you have also a Ping / Pong implementation.

So you can expect that the connection loss is detected by sending some Ping / Pong WebSocket.